# AWS JS SDK: getSignedUrl and expiration times with clock skew

Tags: aws-sdk-js

How does the AWS correctClockSkew option work with preSignedUrls? I've got an S3 server hosting several files, which I'm trying to download using some javascript in a browser. The times of the browser and the server are out of sync by about ~5 seconds. If I perform the following from my browser, I get an error saying the link has expired (almost immediately after I generate it):

```js
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {                               
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: objectName,
    Expires: 5
}, 
function(err, url) {
    if (err) {
        Alertify.dialog.alert('Could not get signed url: ' + err);
    } else {
        window.location = url;
    }
});
```

I've looked at setting the "correctClockSkew" config option, but looking at its description it doesn't seem like it would solve this problem:

> whether to apply a clock skew correction and retry requests that fail
>   because of a skewed client clock

This seems like it would retry a request that fails if the request to getSignedUrl failed because of a clock skew issue, but in this case, the clock skew is small enough to pass the getSignedUrl request but great enough to cause the URL to be immediately expired.

Comment: Did you check doing clock sync using ntp package?
 http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/linux-ntp-server-client

Comment: That won't help me here. This is javascript running on a browser and I cannot assume a client's browser is going to be synced.

Comment: Is there a reason the URLs are only valid for 5 seconds? Clock skew of up to 5 minutes (300 seconds) is routine in distributed systems.

Comment: With this application, security is sensitive. No one likes the idea of having a public url that's able to access a resource, I thought by requesting a URL for a short window and immediately downloading it, it would minimize potential security issues. But maybe that's the wrong path to take. I couldn't find a good example of how to use a "getObject" call using the javascript SDK to trigger a download in a browser. Every example I see uses a pre-signed URL.